# Is it possible to delete an instance of a class that automatically removes it from all lists in which it is an element?

Tags: python, list, class, instance, del

I have an instance of a `class` which appears as an element in multiple `list`s. I want to delete the instance and simultaneously remove it from every `list` in which it is an element. Is this possible?

Comment: Anything is possible (and I can think of a way to do what you are saying), but I can't think of a way to do it that isn't basically a hack.

Comment: This kind of sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). _Why_ do you want to do this? There is probably something better you can do like throw and then handle a particular exception when you hit the "expired" instance in your lists.

Comment: If you _do_ want something like this, we need to define boundaries from the problem. How thoroughly can something like this be "deleted"? If I serialize one of those lists as one of your callers, do you expect to be able to go find that file and edit it? (An extreme example just meant to demonstrate the vast possible scope problems here.)

Comment: One possible "hack" would be to maintain a dictionary from elements to lists of list references, which would have to be updated every time you added an element to a list. Alternately, you could keep this lists of lists inside the object itself, and overwrite its destructor to delete itself from all the lists.

Comment: My motivation is as follows: I'm creating an agent-based simulation. Agent() is the relevant class.  Agents must on occasion be removed from the simulation. It seems intuitive to me that deleting the instance would free up memory. It would be nice if this also removed the instance from lists it belonged to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One answer to this is to always allow the objects that you are putting into the lists to manage list membership. For example, rather than saying

```
listA.append(objectA)
```

you would use

```
objectA.addToList(listA)
```

This would allow you to internally store a list of all list that contain `objectA`. Then, when you want to delete `objectA`, you need to call a method like this:

```
def cleanup(self):
    for listToClean in myLists:
        listToClean.remove(self)
```

This does put some strong limitations on your program though - for example, if a copy is made of one of these lists, then the objects will not have a reference to that copy. You have to work with the assumption that any copy of a list (don't forget that slices are copies, too) may have obsolete objects in it, which would mean that you would want to be working with the original lists as frequently as possible.

Comment: Not a bad OO solution. If you ever wanted to use this in parallel or a multi-threaded environment, having some object modify arbitrary lists that it doesn't necessarily encapsulate could lead to some real issues.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [weakref.refs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.ref):

```
class WeakRefList(list):
    def __init__(self, args):
        list.__init__(self, [self.weak(item) for item in args])
    def append(self, item):
        list.append(self, self.weak(item))
    def weak(self, item):
        return weakref.ref(item, self.remove)

class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

orig = [Object('Foo'), Object('Bar')]
weaklist = WeakRefList(orig)
orig.append(Object('Baz'))
weaklist.append(orig[-1])
print(orig[0])
# <__main__.Object object at 0xb748aaac> 
print(weaklist)
# [<weakref at 0xb7487a54; to 'Object' at 0xb748aaac>,
#  <weakref at 0xb7487a7c; to 'Object' at 0xb748ab6c>,
#  <weakref at 0xb7487aa4; to 'Object' at 0xb748ac2c>]
```

You call the `weakref` to recover the original object. If it does not exist, calling the `wearef` returns `None`:

```
print(weaklist[0]())
# <__main__.Object object at 0xb748aaac>
```

It returns exactly the same object:

```
print(orig[0] is weaklist[0](), id(orig[0]), id(weaklist[0]()))
# (True, 3074992812L, 3074992812L)
```

You can access its attributes (or methods) as usual:

```
print(weaklist[0]().name)
# Foo

for item in weaklist:
    print(item)
    # <weakref at 0xb7487a54; to 'Object' at 0xb748aaac>
    # <weakref at 0xb7487a7c; to 'Object' at 0xb748ab6c>
    # <weakref at 0xb7487aa4; to 'Object' at 0xb748ac2c>

print([item.name for item in orig])
# ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']
print([item().name for item in weaklist])
# ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']
```

And finally, here's the property you are seeking: deleting items from `orig` automatically deletes them from `weaklist` as well:

```
while orig:
    item = orig.pop()
    del item
print(orig)        
# []
print(weaklist)
# []
```